# How do I get Sublime Text 2 to properly color SQL even if its inside a php string?

Tags: text-editors, syntax-highlighting, sublime-text-2

I have the following code in a php page:

```
<?php

$query = "
    SELECT data 
    FROM table 
    WHERE param = 1 
";
```

Since this sql is wrapped inside quotations in a php document, everything shows up a solid green (or whatever color you have set for a string's syntax highlight).

Is there a way to get sublime text 2 to properly color the sql even with it inside a php string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Sublime this code works great:

`$query = "SELECT data FROM table WHERE param = 1 ";`

Don't add new line after '='

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit the `PHP.tmLanguage` located in `Data\Packages\PHP`. You should probably set a regex rule (as MySQL queries begin with `SELECT`/`DESCRIBE` etc.) and assign proper context.